# Visual Studio Code snippet as keyboard shortcut key

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I know how to modify and create code snippets and I know how to modify shortcut keys, but how does one bring those 2 together?

Comment: You access snippets by typing the start of their identifier. As far as I know, you cannot assign them custom hotkeys, at least not without extensions (about which I don't know any). I let my templates all start with a specific character, identify them by a follow-up letter, and then that's it, almost like a hotkey.

Comment: You could use [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/)

Comment: ... if you use Windows. Which a lot of developers don't.

Answer (score 53):

Note that the line below will open a list of snippets defined for the language you are currently using (and you don't want that)

```
"args": { "snippet": "'$TM_SELECTED_TEXT'" }
```

Whereas with the below line the snippet given as argument will be executed right away

```
"args": { "name": "your_snippets_name" }
```

Here's how I defined a snippet for HTML where I wanted to select a text and when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> the text to become enclosed in `<strong></strong>` tags:

```
"make_strong": {
    "prefix": "strong",
    "body": [
        "<strong>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT${1:}</strong>"
    ],
    "description": "Encloses selected text in <strong></strong> tags"
}
```

> Note the `${1:}` above - what this does is that it places the cursor there. This enables you to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> at cursor and then have the cursor placed inside the `<strong></strong>` tags. When selecting a string and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, the string will enclosed in `<strong>` tags and the cursor will be placed before the closing `</strong>` tag. Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> at this point, will put your cursor after the closing `</strong>` tag.

And added in my `keybindings.json` the following:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "make_strong" }
}
```

**UPDATE JUNE 2nd, 2021**

Since this is getting lots of views, I am posting some of the snippets I use, maybe it will be useful to someone

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+u",
    "command": "editor.action.transformToUppercase"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
    "command": "editor.action.transformToLowercase"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "insert_strong" }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+i",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "insert_italic" }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+u",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "insert_underline" }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+p",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "insert_paragraph" }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+space",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "insert_nbsp" }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "name": "insert_br" }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Can I ask how to set it up when text is selected it will go in between the `<stong>` tags, but if there's no text selected it will put the cursor at that location?

Comment: @mesqueeb, I have updated the answer with what you were looking for

Comment: if you use <strong>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT{1:}</strong>, after pressing CTRL+B it makes the word strong, but also adds {1:} after each selected word.

Comment: fixed it - there was a $ (dollar sign) missing before "{1:}"

Comment: Note that the version: `"args": { "snippet": "'$TM_SELECTED_TEXT'" }` works perfectly fine (remembering selected text was added to vscode after the question/answers).  It does not open a list of snippets.  A separate snippet is no longer necessary.

Comment: Yup, that worked for me. Took me two seconds. Whereas I couldn't make it work from VSCode's own documentation after 30 minutes...

Comment: Should be the first answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

It would seem that, as of version 1.9, Visual Studio Code can do what you are looking for, no other extensions necessary.

From https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_insert-snippets

"You can now bind your favorite snippets to key bindings. A sample that encloses a selection with single quotes looks like this:"

Add the snippet below to `keybindings.json` (open Keyboard Shortcuts editor and click on the `For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json` link)

```
{
    "key": "cmd+k",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "snippet": "'$TM_SELECTED_TEXT'" }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Here are 3 steps to create a code snippet along with a shortcut.**

> **1**. **Code** -> **Preferences** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts**

[image]

> **2**. Click on icon for **keybindings.json** file

[image]

> **3**. Add JavaScript objects for Code Snippet/Shortcuts

[image]

For example i have created snippets for logging purposes as I mostly work with JavaScript Frameworks.

1.`console.log('')` with shortcut **Control (or Ctrl) ⌃** + **l**

2.`console.warn('')` with  **Control (or Ctrl) ⌃** + **w**

3.`console.error('')` with **Control (or Ctrl) ⌃** + **e**

**Code:**

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.log('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1')$2"
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.warn('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1')$2"
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "console.error('${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1')$2"
    }
}
```

Comment: A very nice simple method.  Here's a snippet for insert the php object operator: 
`{
        "key": "ctrl+.",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'php'",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "->$0",
        }
    }`

Answer (score 2):

1. Call Command Palette in View menu
2. Hit "shortcuts json" and OK
3. Then append under code blocks

   ```
   {
     "key": "shift+alt+l",
     "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
     "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'js'",
       "args": {
       "snippet": "console.log($1);$0",
       }
   },
   {
     "key": "shift+alt+l",
     "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
     "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'dart'",
     "args": {
       "snippet": "print($1);$0",
     }
   },
   ```

If you press Shift+Alt+L in JavaScript then
put "console.log();" to your editor,

And press Shift+Alt+L in Dart then
put "print();" to your editor,

with the same shortcut.

Comment: This is useful if you are using some very simple snippests.