# Create custom keymap in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I want to create a custom keymapping in vscode that would help me write special text faster when writing in LATEX.

Example of what I mean :

I'm using the `\color{choosen_color}{text}` command in latex. 
I have written "`some text`" and within that I want to use the above command over the "`text`" word.
Instead of having to write it manually, I want that if I select "`text`" and then press `Ctrl+Alt+c`, vscode automatically writes `\color{}{text}` and place the cursor between the first brackets.

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: unrelated to your question, but the syntax is wrong. Do you maybe mean `\textcolor{choosen_colour}{text}` or `{\color{choosen_color} text}`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Hi, that's an example of a `\newcommand` I made for using `\textcolor` while escaping any `_` in minted.

Comment: So you are redefining the `\color` macro?

Comment: To be fully clear, I named it `mintcolor` which I believe isn't a reserved macro. But that's not my point, it was just an example of the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: OK, that's good! Redefining `\color` could give such a mess :)

Comment: in the keybinding execute a snippet with the `selected text` variable, see snippet doc page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to @rioV8 I figured it out.

What I was looking for is the VsCode Keymapping snippets.

More about it here :
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_insert-snippets
[Visual Studio Code snippet as keyboard shortcut key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333639/visual-studio-code-snippet-as-keyboard-shortcut-key)