# Create hotkeys at visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

I would like to create a hotkey, because there is a piece of code that I need to write frequently, I would like to press two keys like Shift+F10 and write that piece of code.

At my searches I just found hotkeys to act at VSC's configs, but I want hotkeys to write code when they are triggered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code snippet as keyboard shortcut key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333639/visual-studio-code-snippet-as-keyboard-shortcut-key)

Comment: Not actually. I need a configuration that when pressing two keys the system writes a recurring code snippet

Comment: The linked question asks the exact same, so how does it not answer your question?