# Swapping "Enter" command with "Cmd + Enter" in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have made some changes in keybindings.json:

```
    {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertLine", // this doesn't work, command not found
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertLineAfter", // to insert line below, this works correctly
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

My idea was to prevent the following situation:

```
print("sentence~") # here I am pushing "Enter" while cursor is in ~ place
print("sentence
")
```

Now, after the change, although cursor is before ") it skips to the new line after pushing "Enter", which is as expected (90% of usage).

My problem now is, that the previous command (after pressing "Enter") exist no more.
So I can't halve the line in the middle (10% of usage) and go to the new line with the rest of the previous line after the cursor.

I am looking for a command which I could pin to "Cmd + Enter". I thought maybe just "editor.action.insertLine" but it's not correct.

Thank you for your help,
sercheese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you can leverage "insert snippet" command feature that calls snippet consisting of single line separator (`\n`):

```
"command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
"args": { "snippet": "\n" }`
```

Thanks: [Visual Studio Code snippet as keyboard shortcut key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333639/visual-studio-code-snippet-as-keyboard-shortcut-key)

Tried something like your requirements with…

```
  {
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": { "snippet": "\n" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.insertLineBefore",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
  },
```

…and it seems to work as intended on Windows. (I've added more restrictive "when" rule to be still able to confirm suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

cmd shift P >> Open keyboard shortcuts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).